What allows trivially copyable types to have padding bits?
Looking at many discussions about low level manipulations of objects in C++ (creation from array of chars, std::memcpy,...), I was wondering how it could work for classes with padding bits:
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Has padding bits
struct Padded {
    char b : 3{0};
    char c{0};
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Padded> << '\n';
    Padded p0;
    Padded p1{1,2};
    // valid according to the standard: objects exists and are trivially copyable
    std::memcpy(&p0,&p1,sizeof(Padded));
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(p0.c) << '\n';
}

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.types#4 defines object representation (the set of bytes, including padding bits) of a given object.
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.fundamental#4 states that:

Each set of values for any padding bits ([basic.types]) in the object representation are alternative representations of the value specified by the value representation.

Meaning, if I understand correctly, that two objects with the same value representation must have also the same object representation, allowing for efficient trivial copy. The padding bits value remains unspecified.
Are my assumptions correct?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/79230763/21691539 partially answers by demonstrating how my interpretation of https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.fundamental#4 was wrong.
Yet my question remains, how can it work, for example with std::memcpy.
I proposed a thought experiment: let say the padding bits are a hash of the object location. In my snippet Padded is still trivially copyable (which is a property that must not depend on implementation details such as the padding bits) but a naive std::memcpy implementation, that would copy all bytes of the object representation, would be broken. Yet std::memcpy processes void * thus does not know the types of objects it's working on. So how can it work in practice (as it is mandated by https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-3)?

"two objects with the same value representation must have also the same object representation" --> +0.0 and -0.0 have the same value (they == each other), yet different bit patterns.  This difference does not involve padding.  It goes into what is meant by the same value.

@chux: I don't think that floats have anything to do with this. IEEE binary floats doesn't have any padding bits, value and object representation is the same. The fact that for some values, == and != acts "unusal" is not because of padding bits, but  == and != have special rules (not just for positive/negative zero, but for NaN as well).

The value of padding bits is unspecified. There is no such thing as "padding bits are a hash of the object location". Of course, if you memcpy'd such a thing, this constraint would be violated. But such a constraint (or any similar) doesn't exist. The main thing about padding bits is that they are not part of the value representation. Unless you explicitly access them by memcpy, or by some char pointer, you don't see any effect of them.

@geza I know but I'm looking for guarantees that these padding bit are effectively "harmless" for operations such as std::memcpy. My thought experiment is there to show that, without constraints, issues may occur. "Unspecified" means, precisely, that a hash of the location is a possible implementation for the padding bits.

@geza FP has to do with OP's "same value representation must have also the same object representation".  Further C++ does not require IEEE adherence.  In addition to +/- 0.0 being equal, it is not uncommon for long double to have padding.  Also IEEE decimal formats also have redundant encodings for some values.  FP (and pointers too) relate to OP's assessment of what it means to be equal value.  OP's later edit hints that equal is more of a memcmp(&a,&b)==0 than a==b thing, yet even that is not specified.

@Oersted Hash depending on the location is not a use of padding that I have encountered.  Hash of the binary data bits yes, but location independent - which works fine with common memcpy().

@geza • on one of my platforms, the 80-bit IEEE binary float is stored in 96-bits (16 padding bits), and the 80-bit IEEE binary float on another platform is stored in 128-bits (48 padding bits).

@chux: OK, what I meant to say is that regarding +0/-0, the reason that == returns true is not because the value representation is the same (and the sign is encoded in padding bits). +0 and -0 have a different value and object representation (there is no padding bits in a IEEE binary float). We may argue whether +0 and -0 have the same value, but I don't think it's a fruitful discussion.

@Eljay: sure, it's common that Intel's 80-bit format (which is not IEEE specified, as far as I know) is stored in 12 or 16 bytes. But crux's example is not about this.

@chux: it's a thought experiment, an example of padding that could break std::memcpy. My expectation is to find what in the standard would prevent that. Until proven otherwise, "unspecified" allows for it (even if it does not exist yet).

@Oersted: I think you misunderstand padding bits. There is no such thing as "hash of the location is a possible implementation for the padding bits". Padding bits are just junk, ignored space. We (programmers, compilers) don't have any intentions to set them. Sometimes padding bits gets zeroed, copied, etc. (if it's better for performance to zero/copy them - for example, if there is a 500-byte struct, with some 1-2 bytes of padding inside, it's better to zero/copy all the 500 bytes, instead of leaving out the 1-2 bytes of padding). But otherwise padding bits are unused, not touched.

@geza It would make sense but all I ask is where is it written in the standard. The closest I find is the paragraph about zero-initialization that specifies that padding bits are also zero initialized. But it's way too indirect to tell they are "junk".

@Oersted: I think the sentence "Each set of values for any padding bits ([basic.types]) in the object representation are alternative representations of the value specified by the value representation." says a very similar thing. Of course, it doesn't call it "junk", but what would you call the bits which doesn't have any influence on the value of a variable that they are part of? The standard doesn't have the subtlest sign of giving any meaning to padding bits. Therefore memcpy cannot break anything regarding padding bits, because there are no defined rules to break.

@geza If "Padding bits are just junk, ignored space." could be supported with specs, I think it would meet OP's goal.  Yet I do not think padding must be ignored, even if it is commonly ignored.  IMO, this is a non-trivial request into spec land - something that takes time to suss out.

@geza I understand what you're getting at. It could make sense but, IMHO, the standard  wording is too vague. I'm not a linguist but the it mixes the (possibly empty) set of values of the padding bit with the value of the all objects. yakk-adam-nevraumont answer is giving a much better wording, I think.

I think you have read that wrong.  If the padding bits differ, this produces "alternative representations" of the same value.
You can copy those padding bits or clear them, and you end up with the same value representation.
The mapping between value representation and object representation is explicitly not bijective.  For certain types, copying the object representation must generate a new value with the same value representation.  But there is no guarantee that comparing object representations gives the same operation as comparing value representations.
The "unspecified" padding bits in the value representation define a freedom of representation of the object representation.

Each set of values for any padding bits ([basic.types]) in the object representation are alternative representations of the value specified by the value representation.

To reword:
Each set of values in the padding bits (each possible value in the unspecified bits) in the object representation are alternative representations (members of the same equivalence class) of the (same) value specified by (each specific) value representation.
So you have value A and value B.  Both have specified and unspecified bits.
For value A, there is a set of object representations, each distinguished by a different set of values in the padding bits, that are all valid object representations of the value A.  And the same is true for B.
None of the object representations of A and B overlap.
A's value representation might be:
0100****0001****

and B might be:
1100****0001****

where * are unspecified bits.
Then
0100 0000 0001 0000
0100 0001 0001 0000
0100 0010 0001 0000
0100 0011 0001 0000

...
0100 1100 0001 0000
0100 1101 0001 0000
0100 1110 0001 0000
0100 1111 0001 0000
0100 0000 0001 0001
0100 0001 0001 0001

...
0100 1110 0001 1111
0100 1111 0001 1111

are the 28 (aka 256) different alternative object representations of the value A.  (A has 8 unspecified bits)

As a small addition to your answer and as OP asked for the low level functions: A memcmp can detect such differences in the padding bytes. A memcmp may report a difference even though the significant bytes are similar. So don't rely on memcmp when there is any padding.

Thus I totally misinterpreted [basics.fund].4. Thus couldn't the padding bit be, for instance, a hash of the memory location. Then memcpycouldn't be implemented efficiently (thus the purpose of the question in title) or it will results in invalid objects?

extrapolating a bit: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Trivial_copy_constructor seems to say that only value representation must be preserved but how can std::memcpy can be aware of that, as it does not know the actual type of the objects (it has void* as inputs) thus it cannot know what bit participate to value representation.

@Thibe it seems that memcmp compares only object representation. From cppref "This function reads object representations, not the object values, and is typically meaningful for only trivially-copyable objects that have no padding.".

@Oersted Yes, in short memcmp compares all bytes and thus is affected by the unknown padding bytes.

Side question, are the padding bits (or intra-member padding bytes, or trailing alignment bytes) accessible through the C++ standard and the C++ abstract machine?  (They can be accessed deus ex machina, by using a char* and rummaging through memory, the same way that a virtual function table can be rummaged through.  But I'd call either one of those as not being cricket.  Implementation detail, and HIC SUNT DRACONES.)

@Oersted memcpy that can handle the padding bits being a hash of the memory location need not be possible to implement?  But, for example, your hardware might have a "value bits mask" that distinguishes between value and non-value bits and does arbitrary things to non-value bits.  (If this is impossible, that isn't a problem for the C++ standard; the C++ standard merely mandates what must be done, not that everything that could be legal for one section is possible given other sections)

@Eljay You can copy the object representation to a byte array (char or whatever) and examine those bits at will?  But no, most access will only touch the value representation.  The point of this wording is to formally describe what compilers naively did with padding and alignment stuff, so you know what you are allowed to assume in portable code.

@Eljay But, imagine a trinary computer.  It runs C++ by never using the 3rd state.  Padding trytes, however, use that 3rd state as a flag in the high-order trib.  It can now use the rest of the tryte to include said hash, and memcpy can detect it as a hashed padding tryte and correct it.
